# asp.net mcv return object from action, and use it in ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm have that ResultOfOperation class that i use to get details about the activity:

```
public class ResultOfOperation
    {

        public string Message1 { get; set; }
        public string Message2 { get; set; }
        public string Message3 { get; set; }

    }
```

And that Jquery function, called from the form on submit:

```
function SubmitForm() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/BindingTest',
                    data: $("#PersonForm").serialize(),
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {

                        toastr.success(data.message1);

                    }
                });
            }
```

And some controller action:

```
public ResultOfOperation BindingTest(Person p)
        {
            //some DB operations.
            var rop = new ResultOfOperation();
            rop.Message1 = "Operation Success";
            return rop;
        }
```

My  is like this:

```
<form id="PersonForm" action="@Url.Action("BindingTest", "Home")" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="firstName" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="lastName" />
            <br />
            <input type="number" name="age" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

My question is how can i use my returning object and show it in toastr.js for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method needs to return a `JsonResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult BindingTest(Person p)
{
    //some DB operations.
    var rop = new ResultOfOperation();
    rop.Message1 = "Operation Success";
    return Json(rop);
}
```

Comment: Thx on the response. I cant see the toastsr, the site just redirect to white page with the text: {"Message1":"Operation Success","Message2":null,"Message3":null}
Why is "JsonResult" is redirect me and didnt stay at the same page?

Comment: Then that would mean your handling a submit button and have no cancelled the default submit (you have not shown the code which calls that method, but add `return false;` as the last line of code in your `SubmitForm()` function.

Comment: I added my <form>

Comment: But you really should be doing this using [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - `$('#PersonForm').submit(function(){ $.ajax({... }); return false; });`

Comment: Its Work. Thx. but didnt understand the difference between $('#PersonForm').submit...... and action="@Url.Action("BindingTest", "Home")"

Comment: Your `@Url.Action()` is just generating the url for the form's `action` attribute. Nowhere where you actually actually executing your `SubmitForm()` function (for example by adding `onclick="SubmitForm()"` in the button) so it was just doing a normal submit. And as a side note, you really should be using the `HtmlHelper` methods to bind to your model